# url rewriting and pass the form's values

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, seo

I'm having e commerce website in php. And now moving to fancy urls, url rewriting.

for that i've variable length of parameters with optional variables too.

for example,

```
http://example.com/product.php?page=e&id=23&color=blue&size=xxl&width=200&height=100
```

Here, the parameters are optional That means, some variables may or may not participage in the url except `id`.

here, `page=e` is fixed and it is not dynamic. ( the reason behind is i've other rewritten rules like `^categories`,  `^toys` etc..

and re-written url should be one of these,

```
http://example.com/e/23/color-blue/size-xxl/
http://example.com/e/26/color-black/width-500/height-900/
http://example.com/e/56/type-shirt/color-white/height-345/size-xl/
```

i've tried below with no luck,

```
RewriteRule ^e/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?page=e&url=$1  [L,NC,QSA]
```

i'm getting all `$_GET` values like this,

```
http://example.com/product.php?page=e&id=23&color=blue&size=xxl&width=200&height=100
```

but i'm trying to achieve like this,

```
http://example.com/e/23/color-blue/size-xxl/width-200/height-100
```

how can i pass the queries with **slashes** and not `&`'s.

that main idea behind above last url is to process the whole fancy url into simple one in php,

and then use those variables in the page script. is there any better solution than this ??

Comment: Even `id` is also optional?

Comment: No. it is compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(e)/([0-9]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]*)(/.*)?$ product.php$5?page=$1&id=$2&$3=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(product\.php)/([^-]+)-([^/]*)(/.*)?$ $1$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```